# Can Gradle handle local dependencies to other than sub-directories?

Tags: gradle

I don't know if I totally got the concept wrong, but I want to create several projects with dependencies to other projects which are not part of the directory structure of a parent project. I know that the normal way of doing this would be to use an external dependency which fetches from some external repository. But in this case, where let's say in project called 'F' a framework is developed, which is used in project 'P'., then P uses F, but F should IMO not necessarily be a sub-project of P as P is only used to test-drive the development of F (but it's not only a unit test). Later in the process, when F is stable, F is separated and can be consumed by other projects via a repository. But during development of F with P as it's test case, it would be nice if that round-trip through the repository could be omitted.

To make matters worse, for the initial development there is more than one test-driving consumer project, which all need to have a dependency to F, but not via an external repository.

My idea is to develop F in some place on the disk with it's own git reposity. The other P like projects reside somewhere else on the disk and have a local file system based dependency to F. Would such a construct be possible in Gradle? If so, where do I start? I scanned the Java examples but couldn't find an appropriate example.

Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Gradle cannot handle adding to a sub-project a dependency contained in a parent project, such as the root project.  It only supports "peer projects" or side-by-side projects in your heirarchy and child projects.  Thus is the syntax:  project(':sub-proj1:sub-proj12') .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gradle project hierarchy is fully virtual. It just has the default that the physical location corresponds to the virtual hierarchy. But you have complete control over this. See: http://gradle.org/0.9-rc-1/docs/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:settings_file

Regarding your other ideas have a look at the following Jira: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRADLE-1014

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a folder hierarchy like this one:

```
Main folder
|- F folder
|  |- .git
|  |- sources
|  |- build.gradle (with parts specific to F)
|- P folder
|  |- sources
|  |- build.gradle (with part specific to P)
|- build.gradle (with common parts)
|- settings.gradle
```

So you can always decide to run gradle on either the F project, the P project or the two alltoegether. It will also allows you to promote you F project alone without the P or any other side projects.

For more up-to-date information, check the [Multi Project Builds chapter](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html) of the Gradle documentation.

Comment: Thank you for this. I had checked this section. This is the standard structure and it would be quite alright. But, what if I do not want P to reside in the same folder as F? I want to be able to add P2 in its own folder, and P3 in its own folder, etc. P2 and P3 belong to different customers and should not see each other. The normal way to achieve this would be a repository where I drop the F artifacts. But because I develop F, P and perhaps P2 and P3 in conjunction, it would be very time consuming to have to travel always over the repository. Or may be not, as it is just some jars somewhere.

Comment: Well, I would say that this is more a SCM issue than a gradle one. I don't know git enough, but, i.e., Mercurial has the concept of sub-repository, which means that each of your Px would be in its "own" repository, included in a bigger one tha contains everything that's in "Main folder". Another example is SVN where you can play with externals, to download, at check out time, some other projects and include them in you folder hierarchy.